# updates in the table are shown after 2nd reload (mysql) why this happens and the updates are not shown in first time?

Tags: php

I am using a colorbox(edit the record) to display the form,The form has the field to upload a video file...
When any file uploaded it is converted to .flv i am using ffmpeg.

while clicking submit button in this pop up box the popup closes and the parent page refreshs.

but after refreshs the it shows the old file....if i again refresh it it shows the newly uploaded file...wat happining here....

i am using codeignitor....

thanks

Comment: Do you have errors and warning turned on? Do you have any code where you can show us what might be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You probably have your code structured something like this:

```
$id = intval($_REQUEST['id']);

// load the video info
$video = $db->fetch('SELECT * FROM videos WHERE id = ?', $id);

// check for new file
if (isset($_FILES['video_file']) && $_FILES['video_file']['error'] == UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
     // process the new file
     move_uploaded_file($_FILES['video_file']['tmp_name'], 'video_files/' . $id);
     // update the video info in the DB
     $db->update('UPDATE videos SET file_name = ? WHERE id = ?', $_FILES['video_file']['name'], $id);
}

// return the video info
echo 'Your video file is ' . $video['file_name'];
```

The problem here is that you are loading the video before you're updating it. You just need to make sure that you're doing your SQL UPDATE before your SELECT.

Comment: k jonathan....my problem is ,after uploading  immediately  i ll close the colorbox(IFRAME).In which submission of video file takes place.while closing color box i ll call the select query.While calling immediately select query it showing old video file name,after few seconds i ll again refresh it ,it shows the new video file name mr.jonathan